# How to find clusters of values over threshold for timeseries

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, outliers

I have timeseries and need to find clusters of values over threshold and plot that cluster on separate plot.

My code example. Unfortunately I don't know how to generate well clustered values.

```
#generate sample data

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")

set.seed(8)

Values <- sample(0:100,24241,  replace = T)

Values <- rpois(24241, lambda=60)

start <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-15 06:10:00")
interval <- 15
end <- start + as.difftime(4, units="days") + as.difftime(5, units = "hours")

DateTimes <-  seq(from=start, by=interval, to=end) 

my_data_sample <- tibble(datetime = DateTimes, Value =  Values)

threshold <-  82


ggplot(data = my_data_sample, aes(x = datetime, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = "darkgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=threshold, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  theme_bw()  +
  labs(
    x= ""    ,
    y = "",
    title = paste("Threshold:", threshold )
    ) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "8 hour", labels = date_format("%b %d - %H:%M")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```

Here is what I need:

[image: example]

I need to find clusters of values over threshold - consecutive or near each other, sort that clusters using cluster length in seconds (longest clusters) or sum of values (most powerful clusters), and plot let's say top 3 of that time periods on separate plots.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find runs that follow some expectation using run-length encoding (RLE). At the RLE level, you can filter out runs that are too short on either side. You can play with the `run_threshold` value until it matches your data.

```
# Put some actual deviating runs in the data
my_data_sample$Value[5001:5100] <- rpois(100, lambda = 80)
my_data_sample$Value[10001:11000] <- rpois(1000, lambda = 80)

threshold <-  82

rle <- rle(my_data_sample$Value > threshold)
# Find sub-threshold values in between super-threshold values,
# convert these to other class
run_threshold <- 20
rle$values[!rle$values & rle$lengths < run_threshold] <- TRUE
# Restructure rle
rle <- rle(inverse.rle(rle))

# Find short super-threshold values to filter
run_threshold <- 5
rle$values[rle$values & rle$lengths < run_threshold] <- FALSE
rle <- rle(inverse.rle(rle))

# Find run starts and ends
rle_start <- {rle_end <- cumsum(rle$lengths)} - rle$lengths + 1

# Format as data.frame for ggplot
rle_df <- data.frame(
  min = my_data_sample$datetime[rle_start],
  max = my_data_sample$datetime[rle_end],
  value = rle$values
)

ggplot(data = my_data_sample, aes(x = datetime, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = "darkgreen") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, fill = value),
            data = rle_df, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=threshold, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  theme_bw()  +
  labs(
    x= ""    ,
    y = "",
    title = paste("Threshold:", threshold )
  ) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "8 hour", labels = date_format("%b %d - %H:%M")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```

[image]

Comment: How to calcuate power of every cluster of values > threshold? Something like this: `rle_df <- data.frame(min = one_machine_privDataOnly$datetime[rle_start],
    max = one_machine_privDataOnly$datetime[rle_end],
    value = rle$values, mean = ???????
  ) %>% filter (value == T)`